# Add Gradle cache to Sonatype Nexus

Tags: gradle, nexus, gradlew, sonatype

Is there an option available to add the Gradle dependency cache to Sonatype Nexus repository so that i can use that cached dependencies for my project later.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way will be writing a Gradle script, that will exact all the artifacts from Gradle cache using Gradle Artifact Query API and save them in a Maven layout. Then you can import them to Nexus or Artifactory.